# Monitors not waking up from hibernate on Linux (Fixed on Windows)

Tags: multiple-monitors, fedora, hibernate, kali-linux, energy-saving

I'm having an issue with waking up my monitors from power saving mode on my Linux systems. First, I'd like to notice that I'm fairly new to Linux, and I'd really appreciate your help.

I'm running triple boot at the moment with dual monitors. I have Windows 10 installed, Fedora 30 ( 5.0.9-301.fc30.x86_64 GNU/Linux ), and Kali Linux (4.19.0-kali4-amd64 GNU/Linux).

After putting my PC to sleep, I can wake it up by PC buttons, keyboard press or mouse click, but my monitors are remaining in power saving mode. I managed to fix this issue on Windows by changing the power settings of   PCI Express and switching Link State Power Management to off. Is there some equivalent to that on Linux?

I tried multiple things from other users seeking help to a similar issue, but nothing worked for me. I have to admit that I worked on it some time ago, therefore I don't remember what I've done exactly, so I'd like to start taking this problem down from scratch.

I'm using graphics card GeForce GTX 1050 Ti and here's xrandr output

```
xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2960 x 1050, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 380mm x 300mm
   1280x1024     59.89*+
XWAYLAND1 connected 1680x1050+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 470mm x 300mm
   1680x1050     59.85*+
```

Please let me know what other informations I can provide in order to solve my issue.
Thanks a lot